# Interface to map values of 2 objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 objects objA and objB

I have a function which accepts value from objB and key from objA.

```
const objA = {
  a:"a",
  b:"b"
}
const objB = {
  a:"a",
  b:"b"
}
checkValues = (type:string,key:keyof typeof objA)=>{
 return  objA[key] === type;
}

checkValues("A",objA.a)
```

But getting type error
**`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'`**

Answer (score 1):

Defining your function like that it can only check the `entries` of the object(so 'a' | 'b'), instead, you calling the function passing `objA.a` which instead refers to the value of the property `a` on the object.

What you can do is:

```js
//Calling the function and passing only 'a' or 'b'
checkValues("A", 'a');
checkValues("A", 'b');
```

```
//Declaring object properties with types through the use of interfaces:
interface MyObj {
    a: 'a' | 'b';
    b: 'a' | 'b';
}

const objA: MyObj = {
  a:"a",
  b:"b"
}
const objB: MyObj = {
  a:"a",
  b:"b"
}
```

You haven't really specified what you need so this is what i would probably do, hope it will help

Comment: thanks! I understood where I went wrong